# Editing an existing List<String> item

Tags: list, flutter, dart

i want to edit list , but i dont know how can i achieve it.

i have pasted my code below

```
Container(
              child: ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: filterList.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int intex) {
                  //  return MenuList(filterList[intex]);

                    return Container
                      (
                      height:75,
                      //color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Card(
                        elevation: 1.0,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0)),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Image(image:AssetImage("images/beef_burger.jpg"),
                                        width: 70,height: 50,),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Column(

                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[

                                          Container(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.2,
                                            //  color: Colors.blue,
                                            child: Text(filterList[intex].itemName,maxLines: 1,),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            child: Text("AED ${filterList[intex].itemPrice}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),

                            Container(
                              // color: Colors.red,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,

                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    width: 50,
                                    height: 50,
                                    // color: Colors.blue,
                                    child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){

                                      if(filterList[intex].counter > 0){
                                        setState(() {
                                          filterList[intex].counter--;
                                        });

                                      }

                                    }, child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/minus.png"),width: 20,height: 20,),),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Text("${filterList[intex].counter}"),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    width: 50,
                                    height: 50,
                                    //  color: Colors.green,
                                    child: FlatButton(onPressed: () async{

                                      setState(() {
                                        filterList[intex].counter++;
                                      });



                                      cartItemList.add({"itemObj":filterList[intex],"quantity":filterList[intex].counter});



                                      //  cartItemList = [{"index":widget.intex,"itemObj":widget.items,"quantity":_itemCount}];

                                      print(addedItems(cartItemList));

                                      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                      await prefs.setStringList('itemList', addedItems(cartItemList));

                                    }, child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/plus.png"),width: 20,height: 20,),),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                    );

                  }),
            ),
```

i have converted list to list to store in shared preference

```
List<String> addedItems(List<dynamic> cartList){


 try {
  var res = cartList.map((v) => 
  json.encode(v)).toList();
  listNew = res;
   return res;
   } catch (err) {
   // Just in case
   return [];
   }
```

when i add item to the cartlist i gets output as

1. added one item

[{"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":1}]

---

2. added same item again

[{"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":1}, {"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":2}]

---

3. added different item

[{"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":1}, {"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":2}, {"itemObj":{"item_price":20.0,"item_name":"English Breakfast","item_img":" ","item_code":"002","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":71,"category_id":12},"quantity":1}]

---

but i want output as when i add same item again

[{"itemObj":{"item_price":22.0,"item_name":"DINE SPECIAL BREAKFAST","item_img":" ","item_code":"001","item_discount":0.0,"item_id":552,"category_id":12},"quantity":2}]

---

Comment: Instead of adding again and again you should first check if the item exist in the list or not. If exist, update the quantity only else add the item.

Answer (score 0):

List has no built in functionality to only add unique items.
You could use a map or check manually if the item already exist.

To check you can use the indexWhere method:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html